# How to fix "code unreachable" problem in python?

Tags: python

This is the code that I am working on started coding recently:

```py
import random

Q1 = input('''would you like to put your own words instead 
of heads or tails if so say yes if not say no, 
if you said no i will exit the code?''')

if 'Q1 = yes':
   
 Q2 = input('''what word(s) or numbers(s) would 
    you like to use in your random 
    word or number picker?(also no 
    spaces in between numbers.)''')
    y = random.choice(list(Q2))
    print(y)

elif 'Q1 = no':

    print(bye)
```

Comment: please add the error snippet too

Comment: Your conditions should be `Q1 == "yes"`/`"No"`, not `'Q1 = Yes`/`No'`

Comment: `if 'Q1 = yes':` - Why are you using quotes here?

Comment: `if non_empty_string` will always be True so the `else` is skipped.

Comment: Oh, and unless you have variables named `y` and `bye` you're in for another surprise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at this line:

```
if 'Q1 = yes':
```

Pay attention that you are using a string for the if condition. therefore it is always a True statement.

instead use this:

```
if Q1 == 'yes':
```

Comment: Equality is checked with "==" in Python ..

Answer (score 0):

There are bunch of syntax mistake, corrections are as follows:

```py
import random

Q1 = input(
    """would you like to put your own words instead 
of heads or tails if so say yes if not say no, 
if you said no i will exit the code?"""
)

if Q1 == "yes": # you need to check equality with `==` between values/variable containing value
    Q2 = input( # Indentation should be consistent across the file as python is sensitive to indent
        """what word(s) or numbers(s) would 
    you like to use in your random 
    word or number picker?(also no 
    spaces in between numbers.)"""
    )
    y = random.choice(list(Q2))
    print(y)
elif Q1 == "no":
    print("bye")
```